# If the surface area of a box is 32 and its volume is doubled what is the new surface area?

Tags: geometry, volume, area

Original surface area :32
Original volume: x

New volume: 2x

What is the new surface area? Please provide an explanation or show work, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: How is the volume doubled? Don't tell me Banach & Tarski...

Comment: It depends on *how* the volume is doubled. Do we simply double its length, for example? Do we quadruple its length and cut its width in half? Do we multiply each dimension by $\sqrt[3]2$? Do we miltiply two of the three dimensions by $\sqrt2$?

Comment: In fact, the new surface area could be the same...

Comment: I believe that with the information supplied that the best one can do is to find the smallest number $B$ such that any surface area $S \ge B$ is achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not too hard (Lagrange multipliers) to show that for a given volume $x$,
the possible outside surface areas $S$ of a (closed) box satisfy
$S \ge 6 \sqrt[3]{x^2}$.

We are given $32 \ge 6 \sqrt[3]{x^2}$, so we have $x^2 \le ({ 32 \over 6})^3$,
that is, an *upper bound* on the volume.

If we double the volume to $2x$, we see that the allowable surface areas
satisfy $S \ge 6 \sqrt[3]{4x^2}$.

Since all we have is an upper bound on $x$, we cannot say very much.

Perhaps the best we can say is that we can guarantee that any surface
area $S \ge 32 \sqrt[3]{4}$ is achievable.

Comment: The box obviously has a well-defined shape and what is searched is a proportionality ratio.

Comment: The question asks what the surface area  and mentions nothing about proportions. Rather than downvoting, you might see the answer as an interesting take on the question. I am sure that you understand that 'obviously has a well-defined shape' and 'hints that the dilation is isotropic' are a little at odds? Perhaps the question was intended exactly as written?

Comment: I fully acknowledge that your answer is quite interesting in its own right and technically considerable, but not recognizing that this is a trivial question of dimensional analysis is close to bad faith and not very helpful to the OP.

Comment: Whoa. I have written an alternative approach to a possibly ill posed question. There were already two answers which added an additional assumption, adding yet another seems truly pointless. But downvoting because my interpretation is different to yours seems harsh, not to mention the implication of bad faith.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thanks for brightening my night :-).

Answer (score 2):

The volume of a box is the product of the three dimensions, while the surface of any face is the product of two dimensions.

Hence if you enlarge all dimensions by a factor $f$, the volume increases by $f^3$ and the total surface by $f^2$.

You know that $f^3=2$. Conclude.

Comment: The keyword, here, is "***if***".

Comment: @CameronBuie: the fact that the problem statement is deemed to be self-contained and has a solution hints that the dilation is isotropic.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The $r:r^2:r^3$ theorem states that if an object is dilated by $r$, then the surface area increases by a factor of $r^2$, and the volume increases by a factor of $r^3$

Comment: The keyword, here, is "***if***".